# Why does Facebook have "like's" instead of "like"s?

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, apostrophe, internet, social-media

I'm not a native English speaker, so I'm sorry if this is obvious but I can't find an explanation.

Why are "like"s usually referred to as `like's` on Facebook? (You can see many instances [here](https://www.google.com/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22like%27s%22&btnG=).)

To use a "word as a word" I would put quotes (if convenient using the apostrophe character in electronic text) around the word and place the plural -s outside them, and it seems that is the norm  except on Facebook, e.g. "like"s.

By the way it seems the same applies to the ["Discours particle" use of like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_particle), as @simchona says in the comments.

Comment: I just saw the "ell" site, if you want to move the question there it's ok

Comment: I don't think it's talking about Facebook--it's talking about using "like" in a sentence, such as "I, like, can't eat soup"

Comment: @simchona No, if you search "like's"(including the quotes) in google the results seem to refer to the facebook ones. I first saw it in this post: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113320/final-s-without-object-ever-correct in the EdwinAsworth comment.

Comment: But that post doesn't refer to Facebook, and your sentence about style would not, contextually, refer to Facebook

Comment: @simchona You're right, reading it again it probably refers to what you said. This raises another question: why are discourse particle "like"s referred to as " like's "? - Anyway that is a further question, if you search as I said you can find many instances that for sure refer to the facebook ones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000135.htm is found the following:

> Apostrophes with Italicized or Underlined Items:
>
> Letters, numbers, symbols, and words used as themselves are italicized
>   or underlined. ...
>
> When these items are made plural, the plural is shown by adding
>   apostrophe s to the underlined or italicized item. The apostrophe and
>   s are not italicized or underlined. ...
>
> I find the *thee*'s and *thou*'s in older writing hard to follow.  (Words
>   as words)

Lynne Truss also cites this usage in *Eats, Shoots and Leaves*.

(Unlike the first source above, Truss mentions the fact that there a few pure plurals allowed by some authorities to include apostrophes.)

Notice that these are talking about general, not Facebook-specific, English usages.

PS: My choice of **like** in the other thread is probably best regarded as arbitrary. Here is a parallel example: 'There are too many *hamburger*'s in your essay.'

Comment: Wow I never heard of this before, is this commonly known by english people, and if so does it come instinctively or it is just taught very hard at school?

Comment: And are these the exact rules everyone follows or are they just the theoretical correct style? In particular the use of quotes is not cited in that page, I assumed that it was universal, was I wrong? And if so, if I put quotes instead of italicizing/underlining the word would you just think it is bad style or you would not even understand that I meant to use a "word as a word"?

Comment: And, do someone really use underlining? In my language I don't think I ever saw it used for this purpose.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should make these questions in a separate "question", they complete this one in a sense.

Comment: I think most English speakers have never even considered the 'word as a word' usage, never mind permitted styles to indicate examples. One often sees signs with misplaced apostrophes (ex's may be allowed, but carrot's and turnip's certainly aren't).